# Выборочное удаление элементов из массива

Tags: php

У меня есть массив $result, он содержит в себе числа вида Вx_с_Вy, где 'x', 'y' - это любые положительные числа (в начале массива всегда буква А) (В, с, _ - это просто символы). Числа задает пользователь. Я пытаюсь убрать из этого массива значения, где x и y повторяются. К примеру пользователь задал какие-то числа, смотрю что задал:

```
print_r($result);
```

> Array ( [0] => A [1] => B1_c_B1 [2] => B1_c_B2 [3] => B2_c_B2 [4] => B3_c_B3 [5] => B4_c_B4 [6] => B5_c_B5 )

Соответственно я хочу убрать отсюда B1_c_B1, B2_c_B2, B3_c_B3 и т.д., оставив только А и B1_c_B2 с последующей записью в новый массив. Пытался следующим образом:

```
$count = count($result);
$my_array = array(); //массив, куда я буду складывать новые, не повторяющиеся значения

for ($i=0; $i <= $count ; $i++) { 
foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
if ($v == "B".$i."_c_"."B".$i) {

} else {
    array_push($my_array, $v);
}
}
}
print_r($result);
```

Но ничего адекватного у меня не выходит. Пробовал и через двойной цикл for:

```
for ($a=0; $a <= $count ; $a++) {
  for ($i=0; $i <= $count ; $i++) {
    if ($result[$a] == "B".$i."_c_"."B".$i) {
    } else {
      array_push($my_array,$result[$a]);
    }
  }
}
```

Был бы благодарен за подсказки или помощь, ибо я все свои варианты перепробовал. Не понимаю, почему способ с for for не работает, до сих пор считаю, что он должен быть рабочим. $a перебирает все элементы массива и для каждого из них $i перебирает и ищет повторяющиеся значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то такое что ли?

```
$my_array = array_filter($result, function($v){ 
                  $tmp = explode('_', $v);
                  return count($tmp) == 1 || $tmp[0] != $tmp[2];
              });
```

Comment: а что здесь $data ?

Comment: ваш массив, очевидно

Comment: мой массив, который я фильтрую - $result, а my_array - это куда я добавляю значения отфильтрованные. Я так понимаю у вас $data это и есть мой $my_array?

Comment: переименовал, если это вам облегчит понимание.

Comment: Именно то, что я и хотел сделать. Спасибо, посмотрю поподробнее насчет этого на сайте php

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr=array( '0' => 'A', '1' => 'B1_c_B1', '2' => 'B1_c_B2'. '3' => 'B2_c_B2', '4' => 'B3_c_B3', '5' => 'B4_c_B4', '6' => 'B5_c_B5');

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
$var=explode('_c_', $value)
if($var[0]==$var[1]){
$arr1[]=$value;

}}
$result = array_diff($arr, $arr1);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: `list($a, $b) = explode(....)` удобнее будет, не надо далее проверять, что в массиве больше одного элемента. плюсанул, что-то я не сообразил разделить по `_c_` :)